# Issues on loop for retrieve the dynamic sql parameter values from dynamic textboxes

Tags: vb.net, loops, dynamic, sqlparameter

all. I am a new VB.NET beginner. I am facing the issue of how to pass the dynamic SQL parameter values from the dynamic textboxes to search the data. I had added control of dynamic textboxes and labels and would like to search the data on the database table based on the dynamic textboxes value inputted from the user. Currently, I can only able to search the data from 1 dynamic textbox value only.

I want all the values from the dynamic textboxes that the user had been entered can be retrieved, and search the data based on the SQL parameter variable name and value entered by the user.

Can someone give me some solutions on how to solve this problem? I had stuck on this problem for a few days. Thank you for all the help!

What I had  tried:

```
Private Sub FilterData()

    Dim count As Integer = 0

    'filterdata for radiobutton
    Try
        For Each TextBox As TextBox In grp2.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox)()
            For Each Label As Label In grp2.Controls.OfType(Of Label)()

                Using connection As New SqlConnection("connectionString")

                    'user key in the SQL statement
                    sql = TextBox1.Text
                    Dim sql2 As String
                    sql2 = sql
                    Dim sp1 As String() = sql.Split(New String() {"where"}, StringSplitOptions.None)
                    sql = sp1(0) & " where " & Label.Text & " = @parameter or " & Label.Text & " =@parameter"

                    If (TextBox.Text <> "") Then
                        count += 1
                        For j As Integer = 0 To count - 1
                            Using cmd As New SqlCommand(sql, connection)
                                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@parameter", TextBox.Text)
                                'cmd.Parameters.Add("@parameter", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 20).Value = TextBox.Text
                                connection.Open()
                                Dim dt As New DataTable()
                                Dim reader As SqlDataReader
                                reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
                                dt.Load(reader)
                                DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
                            End Using
                        Next
                    Else
                        GetData()
                    End If
                    'cmd.Dispose()
                    connection.Close()
                End Using
            Next
        Next

    Catch ex As Exception
        'MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, if you have a 1:1 correspondence between `Labels` and `TextBoxes` then you should not be using two nested `For Each` loops, because that is going to pair up each and every `Label` with each and every `TextBox`. What you should be doing is creating arrays and then using a single `For` loop to access the pairs of controls:

```vb
Dim labels = grp2.Controls.OfType(Of Label)().ToArray()
Dim textBoxes = grp2.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox)().ToArray()

For i = 0 To labels.getUpperBound(0)
    Dim label = labels(i)
    Dim textBox = textBoxes(i)

    '...
Next
```

As for build the SQL and adding the parameters, I would tend to do it something like this:

```vb
Dim labels = grp2.Controls.OfType(Of Label)().ToArray()
Dim textBoxes = grp2.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox)().ToArray()
Dim criteria As New List(Of String)
Dim command As New SqlCommand

For i = 0 To labels.getUpperBound(0)
    Dim label = labels(i)
    Dim textBox = textBoxes(i)
    Dim parameterName = "@" & label.Text.Replace(" ", "_")

    criteria.Add($"[{label.Text}] = {parameterName}")
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue(parameterName, textBox.Text)
Next

Dim sql = "SELECT * FROM MyTable"

If criteria.Any() Then
    sql &= " WHERE " & String.Join(" OR ", criteria)
End If

command.CommandText = sql
```

Comment: hi, i tried your code, and has syntax error on:criteria.Add($"[{label.Text}] = {parameterName}")

Comment: @aliceteh, what version of VS are you using? That line uses string interpolation, which is basically built-in language support for complex formatting. It was first supported in 2015 I think, although it may have been 2017. If you're using an older version, you can use `Striing.Format` instead: `criteria.Add(String.Format("[{0}] = {1}", label.Text, parameterName))`.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should begin to separate UI and data logic here is an example of implementation:

**First you have a table in database:**

```
CREATE TABLE Customer (
    Id              INT IDENTITY (1, 1) PRIMARY KEY,
    FirstName       VARCHAR (255) NOT NULL,
    LastName        VARCHAR (255) NOT NULL,
    Phone           VARCHAR (25),
    Email           VARCHAR (255) NOT NULL,
    Street          VARCHAR (255),
    City            VARCHAR (50),
    State           VARCHAR (25),
    ZipCode         VARCHAR (5)
);
```

**Then you create the underlying entity in VB. Net:**

```
Public Class Customer
    Public Property Id As Integer
    Public Property FirstName As String
    Public Property LastName As String
    Public Property Phone As String
    Public Property Email As String
    Public Property Street As String
    Public Property City As String
    Public Property State As String
    Public Property ZipCode As String
End Class
```

**Data loader**

Now you need a data access component that loads records to a list of this above entity here a nice implementation:

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class CustomerDataAccess
    Public Property ConStr As String

    Public Sub New(ByVal constr As String)
        constr = constr
    End Sub

    Public Function GetCustomersByCriterias(constraints As Object) As List(Of Customer)
        Dim query As String = "SELECT Id, FirstName, LastName, Phone, Email, Street, City, State, ZipCode
                             FROM   [dbo].[Customer] "
        Dim result = New List(Of Customer)()

        Using con = New SqlConnection(ConStr)

            Using cmd = con.CreateCommand()
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
                cmd.CommandText = query

                '' here the magic to add dynamic criteria coming from constraints
                cmd.ApplyConstraints(Of Customer)(constraints)

                con.Open()
                LoadCustomerData(cmd, result)
            End Using
        End Using

        Return result
    End Function

    Private Sub LoadCustomerData(ByVal cmd As SqlCommand, ByVal result As List(Of Customer))
        Using rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader()
            Dim idIdx As Integer = rdr.GetOrdinal("Id")
            Dim firstNameIdx As Integer = rdr.GetOrdinal("FirstName")
            Dim lastNameIdx As Integer = rdr.GetOrdinal("LastName")
            Dim phoneIdx As Integer = rdr.GetOrdinal("Phone")
            Dim emailIdx As Integer = rdr.GetOrdinal("Email")
            Dim streetIdx As Integer = rdr.GetOrdinal("Street")
            Dim cityIdx As Integer = rdr.GetOrdinal("City")
            Dim stateIdx As Integer = rdr.GetOrdinal("State")
            Dim zipCodeIdx As Integer = rdr.GetOrdinal("ZipCode")

            While rdr.Read()
                Dim item = New Customer()
                item.Id = rdr.GetValueOrDefault(Of Integer)(idIdx)
                item.FirstName = rdr.GetValueOrDefault(Of String)(firstNameIdx)
                item.LastName = rdr.GetValueOrDefault(Of String)(lastNameIdx)
                item.Phone = rdr.GetValueOrDefault(Of String)(phoneIdx)
                item.Email = rdr.GetValueOrDefault(Of String)(emailIdx)
                item.Street = rdr.GetValueOrDefault(Of String)(streetIdx)
                item.City = rdr.GetValueOrDefault(Of String)(cityIdx)
                item.State = rdr.GetValueOrDefault(Of String)(stateIdx)
                item.ZipCode = rdr.GetValueOrDefault(Of String)(zipCodeIdx)
                result.Add(item)
            End While
        End Using
    End Sub
End Class
```

**Extensions methods**

Below are extensions methods referenced above that do the magic you are looking for:

DataReader extensions to make it easy to read values from SalDataReader with Dbnull exfeptional case and casting

```
Module DataReaderExtenions
    <Extension()>
    Function GetValueOrDefault(Of T)(row As IDataRecord, fieldName As String) As T
        Dim ordinal = row.GetOrdinal(fieldName)
        Return row.GetValueOrDefault(Of T)(ordinal)
    End Function

    <Extension()>
    Function GetValueOrDefault(Of T)(row As IDataRecord, ordinal As Integer) As T
        Return (If(row.IsDBNull(ordinal), Nothing, row.GetValue(ordinal)))
    End Function

    <Extension()>
    Function GetValueOrDefaultSqlite(Of T)(row As IDataRecord, fieldName As String) As T
        Dim ordinal = row.GetOrdinal(fieldName)
        Return row.GetValueOrDefault(Of T)(ordinal)
    End Function

    <Extension()>
    Function GetValueOrDefaultSqlite(Of T)(row As IDataRecord, ordinal As Integer) As T
        Return (If(row.IsDBNull(ordinal), Nothing, Convert.ChangeType(row.GetValue(ordinal), GetType(T))))
    End Function
End Module
```

Command extensions that lets you extract criteria from an anonymous object values:

```
Imports System.Reflection
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices


Module CommandExtensions
    <Extension()>
    Function AddParameter(command As IDbCommand, name As String, value As Object) As IDataParameter
        If command Is Nothing Then Throw New ArgumentNullException("command")
        If name Is Nothing Then Throw New ArgumentNullException("name")
        Dim p = command.CreateParameter()
        p.ParameterName = name
        p.Value = If(value, DBNull.Value)
        command.Parameters.Add(p)
        Return p
    End Function

    <Extension()>
    Function ToDictionary(data As Object) As Dictionary(Of String, Object)
        If TypeOf data Is String OrElse data.[GetType]().IsPrimitive Then Return New Dictionary(Of String, Object)()
        Return (From [property] In data.[GetType]().GetProperties(BindingFlags.[Public] Or BindingFlags.Instance)
                Where [property].CanRead
                Select [property]).ToDictionary(Function([property]) [property].Name, Function([property]) [property].GetValue(data, Nothing))
    End Function

    <Extension()>
    Sub ApplyConstraints(Of TEntity)(cmd As IDbCommand, constraints As Object)
        If constraints Is Nothing Then Return
        Dim dictionary = constraints.ToDictionary()
        Dim whereClause = " WHERE "

        For Each kvp In dictionary
            Dim columnName = kvp.Key
            Dim propertyName = kvp.Key
            Dim prefix = "@"c
            Dim value = kvp.Value
            whereClause += $"{columnName} **like** {prefix}{propertyName} AND "
            cmd.AddParameter(propertyName, value)
        Next

        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(whereClause) Then Return
        cmd.CommandText += whereClause.Remove(whereClause.Length - 5, 5)
    End Sub
End Module
```

**Example:**

After coded all these stuff now you can do the following:

```
Dim DataGridView1 As DataGridView = New DataGridView()
Dim ConStr As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("MyApp").ConnectionString
Dim dal As CustomerDataAccess = New CustomerDataAccess(ConStr)
Dim criterias = New With {.FirstName = "%James%", .LastName = "%Nadin%"}
DataGridView1.DataSource = dal.GetCustomersByCriterias(criterias)
```

Despite all this code you are still need to bind your textbox (after naming them correctly) to a SearchEntity and use this entity to provide criterias

I hope this material can help you tackle your issue and incite you to improve your architecture & dev skills